# How to create a VR 360 photo viewer in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr-sdk

Can someone guide me to create a VR photo viewer in Unity using the Google VR (GVR) sdk. Thanks

Comment: Changes made...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps in Unity:

> 1. Add a new `Sphere` `GameObject`.
> 2. In your assets Create new `Material`-> change its `albedo` texture with your 360 photo.
> 3. Grab the `Material` and apply it to your `Sphere`.
> 4. Position the main `Camera`/`Player` inside the `Sphere` .

Voila